# Why does the combination of @Environment and .onChange cause the view to redraw itself?

Tags: swiftui

Build this very simple app and observe the logs as you minimize the app (or put it in the background) and make bring it back.

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct DemoApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            FocusedView()
        }
    }
}

struct FocusedView: View {
    @Environment(\.locale) private var locale
    
    @FocusState private var isEmptyFocused: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        let _ = Self._printChanges()
        EmptyView()
            .onChange(of: isEmptyFocused) { _ in
            }
    }
}
```

You should get a new `FocusedView: _isEmptyFocused changed.` each time.

Comment either `@Environment` or `.onChange(of: ) {}` and it's silent.
But having both triggers a redraw.

The @Environment value doesn't have to be `locale`, it can be something else.

Comment: did you ever solved this ? i also experience a redraw of a view only because i call `.onChange(of: isFocused)` and if i have a bunch of this views in a ScrollView or a List they all redraw (although isFocused isn't participating in view's body, and each view in the scroll/list needs to have it's own private instance member of isFocused), any thoughts on that would be appreciated

Comment: @Shaybc unfortunately, I did not, and I forgot to ask during the Ask Apple sessions.